# How to automatically extract an image from surroundings?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I have an Instagram screenshot from mobile and I would like to automatically extract the main image only, cutting out all the surroundings and text. I'm thinking on of edge detection or Hough transform, any elegant and simple solution??

Please consider that the image may not always be centered and that sometimes it only shows partially as in the example below.

Thanks!!

Sample images:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach using OpenCV Python

- Convert image to grayscale
- Perform canny edge detection
- Perform morphological transformations
- Find contours and sort by largest contour area
- Extract ROI

---

Canny edge detection (left) then perform morphological transformations to smooth image (right)

```
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 5, 150, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
```

[image]
[image]

Now we find contours and sort by the largest contour area. The idea is that the largest contour will be the main image. Even if the image is not centered, it should be the largest area. An additional filtering step could be to add in [aspect ratio](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html) to ensure that the contour is a square/rectangle.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    break
```

[image]

Finally to extract the ROI, we can use [Numpy slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943596/check-only-particular-portion-of-video-feed-in-opencv/55943724)

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 5, 150, 1)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    break

cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.imwrite('canny.png', canny)
cv2.imwrite('close.png', close)
cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```